Why did the Singapore Dollar Witness Such Sharp Occasional Spikes Against the Rand?
I have a business trip to South Africa coming up (first time), so was just looking at their currency out of curiosity, and as an estimate of costs and the plot had some surprise for me.

It seems against my home currency (Singapore dollar) the rand stayed stable (~13 rand/sgd for now), except for a few massive spikes that sends the exchange rate soaring through the sky.
What do these indicate? Can any event be that short lived to have a sudden spike and then everything returns to normal? Or, even if it is a few traders trying something funny (shorting or liquidating a huge position) can they really influence the market that much without fundamentals?

I would wager it's dodgy data in Yahoo's feed.  Free data feeds don't bother doing the cleanup work to remove them.

The Iranian rial has a spike on Google finance, see https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/52939/37817. It's what it is with free data sources.
